# Protected Videos not Playing Ubuntu 13.10 (Amazon Prime)

Tags: google-chrome, flash, 13.10, hal

I am unable to play Amazon Prime videos with the Chrome/Firefox browser. I've tried deleting the Flash folder and re-installed the OS.

Ubuntu 13.10
Flash Version: `flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.310ubuntu1`

Youtube works but not Amazon Prime.

Try 1: **Clear Cache Flash**

```
cd ~/.adobe/Flash_Player
rm -rf NativeCache AssetCache APSPrivateData2
```

Try 2: **Install Older version of Flash**

```
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/Flashplayer.so
```

Some other sites have installing HAL and running hald but that was not working either as it seems to be a deprecated.

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer over at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144347 and it worked like a charm in Chromium.  I haven't tested it in Firefox.

Basically, you have to manually download and install HAL, since it doesn't exist in the 13.10 repository.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: My apologies.  I don't yet have the reputation to be able to post more than one link in an answer yet, so I had to just post the link to the answer.